# Displaying progress of transcoding using streamio gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm using the Streamio gem for Rails to transcode a video file to .webm format. I'm able to display the progress of the transcoding on the console using:

```
movie.transcode("public/uploads/#{current_user.id}/#{@userfile.name}.webm") { |progress| puts progress }
```

It's showing the progress on the console like this:

[image]

My question is, how do I display this on the browser? Where the user can actually see the progress of the transcoding?

Comment: you can use progess chart of jquery to display it

Comment: `ActionController::Live`?

Comment: What's `ActionController::Live` ?

Comment: I also face this  same problem. @Swaathi K, you found any proper solution for this ? If yes then please please share that :).

Comment: Yup. You need to use Websockets. The easiest solution was to use a service like Pusher. Just open up a channel, and pass the progress data through it. On the client side you'll have to listen to the channel and display it using some progress graph.

Comment: Thank you @SwaathiK, it's work for me. But there i one more problem with this. When i upload video from two different browser then it's update only in one browser. It's mix up other browser's output in first browser.